# a word for an academic text translation

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, academic-writing

I am translating an academic study on manuscripts. In the source language, there is a word that requires a one-word translation for the idea of both reading and interpreting. I haven’t yet found any word that would convey the idea.
I would be grateful to receive answers.
Best regards, Margaret

Comment: Hello Margaret. You don't need advice like 'But why can't you use a phrasal workaround'; you know the type of translation you need to produce. You're doubtless aware of the fact that semantic gaps exist in the lexicon. _But ELU requires that you show evidence/s of your own research. Which references have you checked for synonyms/near synonyms of 'read/ing' and of 'interpretation' in the search for a useable overlap?_

Comment: No word ever requires a one-word translation. That is the exact opposite of how translation works. And that's a good thing, otherwise we would never be able to translate anything at all. Not even a sentence as simple as "I have a dog" into a language as flexible as Russian.